# Is there a way to set one single condition to all breakpoints in gdb for debugging Cpp code?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have to debug a code in which i want to debug only after certain number of iterations. For eg. one debugging after 1000 iterations, the next after 8000+ iterations. Since I've a lot of breakpoints, changing the condition for each one is tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that:

- Use `set confirm off` so GDB doesn't prompt you with "are you sure you want to do that" prompts
- Use `disable` to disable all breakpoints
- Add a new breakpoint at the start of the loop
- Attach `enable` command to the new breakpoint (this will re-enable all other breakpoints when this one fires)
- Set `ignore` count on the new breakpoint to 1000.

Enjoy your new debugging prowess.

Comment: How to also disable the breakpoints after iteration 1000, and reset the trigger, in case one exits the loop and comes back to it (as part of normal program flow) ? Your suggestion, though valid in and of itself, is a "fire once" solution. I need "fire every time the condition is met, but not before or after".